# Problems when selecting "Save for web"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, mac

I'm in the process of creating my name in Photoshop, but I have a problem.

I type in my name. I use the "free transform" to scale to the size that I want. I make sure that the "anti-aliasing" is set to smooth.

I then go into `File > Save for Web`. I make sure that it'll save the file in the GIF format and save to my desktop.

Then open the image that I saved. It opens in the default image program for Apple computers and come to find out there is some type of white outline around my name.

How to I remove the white outline?

If you would like to see pictures of what I'm specifically talking about, please let me know.

Comment: Hi leo, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Pictures would help, indeed, as would a breakdown (or a screenshot) of your *.gif settings. Thanks! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Gif just supports 1-bit transparency. That means that a pixel is either transparent, or a color. So all the antialiasing is being exported as a mix between the text color and the background color (or white). Use a 24-bit png, that will allow you to have transparency levels.

Comment: Thats right, this time I use only .png!